# Swift Seg Fault Passing a Protocol to a Function

Tags: swift, generics, swift-protocols

I'm getting a seg fault when I run a piece of Swift code.

Please note, I don't have a mac with xcode, I'm playing with Swift in ReplIt and Swift Playgrounds on my iPad.

Here's the code:

```swift
public protocol Funct {
  associatedtype Element

  func fmap<B>(_ fn: (Self.Element) -> B) -> Self
    where Self.Element == B
}

extension Array: Funct {
  public func fmap<B>(_ fn: (Element) -> B) -> Array<B> {
    return self.map(fn)
  }
}

print("Hello it: \([1,3,4,5].fmap { it in "hi \(it + 10)" })") // this works fine

extension Optional: Funct {
  public func fmap<B>(_ fn: (Wrapped) -> B) -> Optional<B> {
    return self.map(fn)
  }
}

// ---------- This works --------------------
let huh: Int? = nil

let yep: Int? = 9000

print("nope: \(huh.fmap { it in "if its here, it's \(it + 1000)" } as Any)")

print("yep: \(yep.fmap { it in "if its here, it's \(it + 1000)" } as Any)")
// -------------- end This works -------------------


func add1000(_ x: Int) -> Int { x + 1000 }

// -------------- Here's where the problems are (I think) ----------------
func usesFunct<F: Funct>(_ functr: F) -> F 
  where F.Element == Int {
    
  return functr.fmap(add1000) // This is what swift playgrounds points to as the problem
}


let workplease: Int? = usesFunct(Optional.some(100))
// I've also tried let workplease: [Int] = usesFunct([1,2,3])

print(workplease as Any)
```

The code will run until it tries to call `usesFunct` and then I get a "segmentation fault: (core dumpted)" in ReplIt. Swift Playgrounds tells me there's an error and to review my code.

Why doesn't `useFunct` work when I pass it an `Optional` or an `Array`? Any chance you know what I'm missing?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I don't have a proper explanation for this so I only post it as a comment, if I add the condition `where Wrapped == Int` for your `Optional` extension the code will execute fine. This is probably not the solution you want but to me it suggests that the correct `fmap` implementation isn't found.

Comment: @Yonat - sorry for the confusion. I'm just wondering why the `useFunct` function doesn't work. That's all. Updated the question to clarify. Thanks!